# perl regex to convert currency

Tags: regex, perl, numbers

i need some help in text cleaning/normalization process

i struck at a place where i need to convert a currency format

input:  $100 million            output: 100 million dollar

input: eur20 million            output: 20 million euros

i'm using perl regex for the cleaning process, help will be appreciated if someone can help me in providing a regex to convert input to output

this is my code so far

```
s/([\$])([0-9\.])([million])/ $2 $3 dollars/g;
```

example number is $4.2 million

this is what i tried for converting dollars symbol into word "dollars" and shift it to end of phrase, but it is not providing the result as expected, it provide me ".2 million" as output

Comment: If you have a problem with your code then you need to show clearly your program, and your input and output data, together with the output that you require. If you haven't written anything yet then you must at least try: Stack Overflow isn't a source of free programming effort.

Comment: We aren't here to write your code and we aren't magicians to predict your code, what have you tried, and what's wrong. Please include a specific problem with what you've tried and what's not working, and include the code, the error, and the line of error. Keep in mind we're not here to give out tutorials nor are we here to write your code. Edit your question and include what I said and your question will **possibly** be answered.

Comment: Also, are you sure it's `$` versus `eur`, but not `€`, and euros versus dollar, but not dollars?

Comment: @choroba it can be eur or €, but i mostly observed eur in the text

Answer (score 1):

`[...]` in a regex introduces a character class, so `[million]` is the same as `[nolim]`, and it matches *one* of those characters.

I'd create a translation table for the currencies in a hash. From the keys of the hash, you can build a regex that matches them, and use it in the replacement:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use utf8;
use feature qw{ say };

my %currency = ( '$' => 'dollar',  # or dollars?
                 eur => 'euros',
                 '€' => 'euros',
);

my $regex = join '|', map quotemeta, keys %currency;

for my $input ('$100 million', 'eur20 million', '€13.2 thousand') {
    ( my $output = $input )
        =~ s/($regex)([0-9.]+ (?:million|thousand))/$2 $currency{$1}/g;
    say $output;
}
```

Comment: this code is worked as expected thank you very much for the code

Answer (score 0):

Your regex does *not* give the result you claim it does.

```
s/([\$])([0-9.])([million])/ $2 $3 dollars/g;
```

With the help of the `/x` modifier we can add whitespace (even newlines and comments) to the pattern to improve readability. Your pattern can then be re-written as

```
s/([\$])        # match a literal $ and capture that as $1
  ([0-9.])      # match ONE digit or a dot and capture as $2
  ([million])   # match ONE character of 'm', 'i', 'l', 'o', 'n'
                # and capture as $3
 / $2 $3 dollars/gx;
```

There is no way `$100 million` matches this pattern and results in `.2 million`. Possible inputs would be
`$3i`, `$.o` or `$9m`. They would give `3 i dollars`, `. o dollars`, and `9 m dollars`.

What you are looking for is a pattern like this:

```
s/\$        # a literal '$'
  ([\d.]+)  # one or more digits or dots, like e.g. '99.5',
            # captured as $1
  \s+       # one or more whitespace
  (million) # the literal text 'million', captured as $2
  /$1 $2 dollars/gx;
```

(or, as a one-liner: `s/\$([\d.]+)\s+(million)/$1 $2 dollars/g;`)

Note that `$2` in this case *always* is `million` and you could also rewrite it as `s/\$([\d.]+)\s+million/$1 million dollars/g;` (omitting the `()` around `million`).

Comment: Thank you, but actually [@choroba's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39678548/5830574) is more general and takes different currencies and magnitudes (thousands/million) into account. I'd go for that one.